# source code for application launcher plasmoid

Tags: kde, software-sources

Can someone please show me where can i find the source code for the application launcher plasmoid? I am unable to find it on KDE base. Do I have to download entire source for KDE ?

Answer (score 0):

**There are many**

There are many application launchers for the KDE:

KDE Userbase: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma_application_launchers

Kubuntu forums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers

**Kickoff**

The default application launcher - Kickoff source: https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-workspace/repository

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been a while: `Kickoff` remains the main KDE app launcher. You can find its git repo [here](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/tree/applets/kickoff).